# Частицы "И ТО" и "ДАЖЕ" - в чем разница?

Tags: семантика, союзы, частицы

Уважаемые любители и знатоки русского языка! В следующих предложениях:

1. Иван Иванович и то пришел на премьеру спектакля.
2. Даже Иван Иванович пришел на премьеру спектакля.
3. Чемпион по самбо и то не смог одолеть его.
4. Даже чемпион по самбо не смог одолеть его.

В указанных предложениях частицы "И то" и "Даже" передают один и тот же смысл. Получается практически всегда конструкции с частицей "и то" можно заменить на конструкции с частицей "даже". Но в чем тогда между ними разница?

Comment: Смысловой разницы нет. Но есть грамматическая разница. "Даже" ставится перед подлежащим. "И то" перед сказуемым. Но если надо сказать: "Иван Иванович даже пришел на премьеру спектакля", то "и то" не поможет. Поэтому делаем вывод, что "даже" более универсальная частица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл *различается*. Вариант "**даже**" (такой-то) акцентирует *производителя* действия, неожиданного в имеющемся контексте. Вариант же "**и то**" указывает на неожиданность самого *действия* (вопреки чему-то названному), а не персонажа, и потому оба предложения с "**и то**" выглядят *некорректными*. Предложение о чемпионе исправляется заменой на "**и тот**" (в этом контексте смысл близок к "**даже**"):

> Чемпион по самбо **и тот** не смог одолеть его.

(ср. *Он чемпион по самбо, **и то** не смог одолеть его*)

С Иваном Иванычем сложнее: для "и то" требуется явное противопоставление причины, по которой И. И. не должен бы прийти.

> Уж насколько Иван Иваныч ленив, **и то** пришел на премьеру спектакля.

Либо акцент можно сместить с *действия* персонажа на *личность* с её свойствами ("и тот"):

> Ленивый Иван Иваныч **и тот** пришел на премьеру спектакля.